# Apply my function to each value in panda column return a copy

Tags: python, pandas

If i load in data with pandas from a csv file like so:

```
LineData = pd.read_csv('calibration.csv')
y = LineData['peak']
```

how can i apply this column to my function below in one go and return a copy of the new values as a new column `y2` without changing the values of the original column `y`:

```
def Test(n):
    return 17.4 + (n - 269) * (2.2/41)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
LineData['y2'] = y.apply(Test)
```

Comment: If i just did `y2 = y.apply(Test)` would that still be the same type as `LineData['y2']` ?

Comment: Yes, It would create another columns after applying function `Test` to each element in column `peak` (meaning `y`) and would not change `y`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fast, vectorized method:

```py
LineData = pd.read_csv('calibration.csv')
LineData['y2'] = (LineData['peak'] - 269) * (2.2 / 41) + 17.4
```